# Can't install Elementary os 6

Tags: system-installation, boot, dual-boot, usb

I can't install Elementary os 6 in four different ways:

1. USB: I'm booting to installation, but then I select custom install it loads and then shows white window.
2. Grml rescue boot(I'm using Zorin os 16): Can't boot just shows many `/init line 49 can't open /dev/sr0 no medium found` lines.
3. UNetbootin: Same as in option option 1.
4. DVD: It's not even booting.

Please help!

Comment: Try reformatting the USB drive, give it a fresh FAT32 partition. I had some trouble with booting the installer, however after trying a few formatting options, I managed to get it working. Also, please give us more information about your system, it's hard to give advice without knowing any specifics.

Answer (score -1):

Me2.  Looking for new distro after Mint 20 screwed up samba amd MX cannot handle hot swapping drives.

Guess what - it aint going to be elementary if you cannot install it.

A lot of modern distros seem to screw up - get back to basics